# how can i send response in node.js after executing all code in a function?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to send a response to the client side after executing all the below code.

Currently,  response is sent to client side first, then below code executed.

Is there any solution to execute all the code first, then send a response to the client side?

Any solution is highly appreciated.

```
router.post('/v2/multiple-kyc-verification', auth, async (req, res, next) => {

    let doc1_msg = '';
    let doc2_msg = '';
    let doc3_msg = '';
    
    if (req.files['doc_front_image1'] && req.files['doc_back_image1'] && req.body.doc_type1) {
    
      let doc_front_image1 = req.files['doc_front_image1'][0];
    
      let doc_back_image1 = req.files['doc_back_image1'][0];
    
      let selfie_image = req.files['selfie_image'][0];
    
      let doc_type1 = req.body.doc_type1;
    
      doc1_msg = await executeKyc(doc_front_image1, doc_back_image1, selfie_image, doc_type1);
    
    }
    
    if (req.files['doc_front_image2'] && req.files['doc_back_image2'] && req.body.doc_type2) {
    
      let doc_front_image2 = req.files['doc_front_image2'][0];
    
      let doc_back_image2 = req.files['doc_back_image2'][0];
    
      let selfie_image = req.files['selfie_image'][0];
    
      let doc_type2 = req.body.doc_type2;
    
      doc2_msg = await executeKyc(doc_front_image2, doc_back_image2, selfie_image, doc_type2);
    
    }
    
    if (req.files['doc_front_image3'] && req.files['doc_back_image3'] && req.body.doc_type3) {
      let doc_front_image3 = req.files['doc_front_image3'][0];
    
      let doc_back_image3 = req.files['doc_back_image3'][0];
    
      let selfie_image = req.files['selfie_image'][0];
    
      let doc_type3 = req.body.doc_type3;
    
      doc3_msg = await executeKyc(doc_front_image3, doc_back_image3, selfie_image, doc_type3);
    
    }
    
    let data = {
      status: "Accepted",
      message1: doc1_msg,
      message2: doc2_msg,
      message3: doc3_msg,
    }
    
    res.status(200).send(data);
});
```

Comment: Can you make your code more readable first ? You are performing 3 times the same actions depending on an object key, you should refactor it to once. What's the server output ?

Comment: server output is below
{
    "status": "Accepted",
    "message1": "",
    "message2": "",
    "message3": ""
}

Comment: It seems that none of the cases are met from your conditions. Is the executeKyc method called ?

Comment: Please include some broader context of the route this code is associated with, such that it can be executed as a [mre].

Comment: border context of route updated and executeKyc  function added below code please check

Comment: you're saying that the response is sent first, then the code above is executed - how did you confirm that? have you made sure through debugging, etc that the conditions in those `if` statements are met?

Comment: yes when i hit this api ,i got result below
{ "status": "Accepted", "message1": "", "message2": "", "message3": "" }
but in backgroung , previous code running and so i am not getting result after executing all code

Answer (score 0):

If none of the `if` conditions is met, your code sends the `data` synchronously, because no `await` is executed. The following simplified example demonstrates this:

- `GET /1` returns `{"branch1":true,"branch2":false}` asynchronously (after 1 second)
- `GET /2` returns `{"branch1":false,"branch2":true}` asynchronously (after 1 second)
- `GET /3` returns `{"branch1":false,"branch2":false}` synchronously

```js
function asyncFunc() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve(true);
        }, 1000);
    });
}

router.get("/*", async function(req, res) {
    let data = {
        branch1: false,
        branch2: false
    };
    if (req.path === "/1")
        data.branch1 = await asyncFunc();
    else if (req.path === "/2")
        data.branch2 = await asyncFunc();
    res.json(data);
});
```